# Connection string Issue with SQLite

Tags: string, sqlite, format, connection

Need a little help with SQLite connection string. I’m using `Mono.Data.Sqlite`. I know If my `database.sqlite` resides in local computer then the format for connection string is `“URI=file:" + "<Directory-Path>/database.sqlite"` and it actually works for me.

But what will be the format of connection string for a network location. Assuming that I have my database on some server and given the following parameters:

```
Server = "swipe.example.com";
Username = "example@swipe.example.com";
Password = <Some Password>;
DatabasePath = "swipe.example.com/database.sqlite";
```

I have tried searching forums several times but found no solution at all. I will really appreciate If you could let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is serverless.
Visit this link for more information :
https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html
You can use http://www.sqlitening.com/